# Calculating group by based on filtered df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I best group by on a df that I want to filter for?

For example if I want to group by a set of columns but filter a df first?

```
df.loc[df['Driver'].isin(drivers), 'Driver'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
```

Above code gives me volume but I want it for as specific city as there is another col called cities in df, thanks!

Comment: can u share an example dataframe, with ur expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Driver'].isin(drivers)].groupby('Cities')['Driver'].value_counts().reset_index()
```

Or [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Driver'].isin(drivers)].groupby(['Cities','Driver']).size().reset_index()
```